# Merging two datasets dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataset, data-wrangling

Hi I have two datasets lets call them dataset1 and dataset2 all of them has one common attribute which is the date. The columns in dataset1 has the attribute in 6am and 6pm and the average of the day. I want to add the attribute in dataset2 in the same manner but the problem is the attribute time was given in every half an hour which make the dimensionality really high . How could I merge

Dataset1
Date- attribute 6am- attribute 6pm- average(per day) attribute

Dataset2
Date - Time - feature

What I want
Dataset1
Date- attribute 6am- attribute 6pm- average(per day) attribute- feature 6am- feature 6pm- average(per day) feature

I am using pandas dataframe.
any advice is appreciated

Comment: You need to use the date and the time slot as merging key.

Comment: but dataset 1 does not have a specific time column but rather the value of the attribute during that time

Comment: Then you should provide a fully explicit example